# Facing Issue Sending Gmail Using Google Gmail API

Tags: python, google-api, gmail

It shows credentials are missing when I try to use the Google Gmail API to send messages. I want to send an email to my other Gmail account using the Google Gmail API.

```
import sys
import requests
import base64
import sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

AccessToken = ""

params = {
        "grant_type":    "refresh_token",
        "client_id":     "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        }

authorization_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

r = requests.post(authorization_url, data=params)

if r.ok:
    AccessToken = str((r.json()['access_token']))

EmailFrom = "Test1@gmail.com"
EmailTo = "test2@gmail.com"

def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
   
    message = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
    raw = raw.decode()
    body = {'raw': raw}
    return body


body  = create_message(EmailFrom, EmailTo, "Just wanna Say Waka Waka!", "Waka Waka!")


url = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send"

header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AccessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post(
    url,
    header,
    body
)
print("\n")
print(r.text)
print("\n")
```

Error:

{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.SendMessage",
"service": "gmail.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] we need to see how you are creating that access token.

Comment: Why are you not using the official python client library?  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Comment: @DalmTo I appreciate your response. My question has been updated, please take a look. And due to a PC issue, I am trying to avoid using Google's Python client library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a google api user, but I've used oauth several times, and your setup is a bit different than what I usually use or what I see from a quick sniff of Google's documention. For example, I use client-creds instead of a refresh token. For what I'm seeing above in your code, no reason to refresh an old token, when you can just mint another one. Compared to yours, usually with oauth, we'll do something like auth=(client_id, client_secret)

Lastly, before you change anything big, when you changed your header to place the AccessToken variable in quotes, did you use an f-string? What is the output of

```
print(header)
```

after you have defined it?  Is it what you expect? If you didn't format it, it's going to have the variable's name rather than value.

If that's all ok, I'd try to write it according to OAuth standards that I've used several times. Not telling you how to do it, but you could try something like:

```
def getKey():
      url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
      client_id = "*yourgoogleclientid*"
      client_secret = "*yourgoogleclientsecret*"
      
      data = {
           'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
          }
    
      r = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(client_id, client_secret))
      key = r.json()['access_token']
      return key


 def getWhatever(key, url):

      header = {
           'Authorization': f'Bearer {key} '
           }

      params = {
            'whatever params': 'you might need'
           }

      response = requests.get(url, headers=header, params=params)
     
     * parse, process, return, whatever you'd like to do with the response.*
```

now to use it....

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
        myKey = getKey()
        whatImLookingFor = getWhatever(myKey, "*https://google_api_endpoint*")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @acousticpanic, for answering this question. I've followed the steps you showed. However, it comes up with a new error message. `{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: client_credentials"
}`  I have used this method to get access tokens for Google Drive API as well, and it works fine, but not with Gmail API